# Using Visual Studio Image Library PNGs in a Windows Form app

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, image, png

My question is about the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx) that comes with VS2008.  In the _Common Elements\Annotations folder, there are PNGs with multiple sizes and I was wondering what the intended use of these is.  Is there an standard way to implement these images, e.g. in a Windows Forms status bar?

Here are three of the PNGs as an example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested usage is to basically copy/paste the sized image you want into a new image file. Then simply use that as an icon or image in your controls as you see fit. All of the PNGs already have a transparent background, so it should be really easy to copy/paste.